# Cloudfront Lambda Egde bug? Change Response Status code in viewer response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

**The question is:** Why is not possible to change http status before return responses in ViewerResponseEvents in lambda edge?

I have a Lambda function that must check every single response and change it's status code based on JSON file that I have in my lambda function. I deployed this lambda function in **Viewer response** because I want that this function executes **before return** every single response. Aws Documentation ( https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/lambdaedge-design-best-practices/ ) says if you want to execute a function for all requests it should be placed in viewer events.

[image: cloudfront events]

So, I've created a simple function that basically is cloning and changing the http status code of response before return it. I did this code for test:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
 const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
 console.log(request);
 console.log(`Original response`);
 const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
 console.log(`Original response`);
 console.log(response);
//clone response just for change the status code
 let cloneResponseReturn = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
 cloneResponseReturn.status  = 404;
 cloneResponseReturn.statusDescription = 'Not Found';

console.log('Log Clone Response Return');
console.log(cloneResponseReturn);

return cloneResponseReturn;
```

};

When I access the log in cloudwatch, it shows that response has http 404 code, but for some reason, cloudfront still returning the response with 200 status code. (*I've cleared browsers cache, tested it in other tools such as postman, but in all of them CloudFront returns HTTP 200)*

CloudWatch Log and Response print:

[image: cloud-watch log]
[image: response]

If I change this function to execute in **origin response** it will work, but I don't want to execute it **ONLY in cache miss** (+as aws tell us that origin events will be executed only in that case+). As origin events are executed only in cache miss, to execute that redirects I would have to create a chache header buster to make sure that origin events will be always executed.

Is really weird this behaviour of edge lambda. Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this? I already tried to clean cache of browsers and tools that I am using for test the requests, also clean the cache of my distribution but still not working.

I've posted the question in AWS Forum a week ago but it still without answer:  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=885516#885516

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the behavior is correct/expected -- when Viewer Response fires, the HTTP status code for the response is already finalized inside CloudFront and can't be changed.  But, I think you may be misunderstanding one or two of the implications of Origin Response triggers only firing on cache misses.  I can't see the value of the `Cache-Control` property `s-maxage` from your screen shot, but if it is `0` then CloudFront isn't caching these responses, so you will never have a cache hit anyway... so every request will be a cache miss.

Comment: Important, too, is the fact that if a response is modified by an Origin Response trigger, and the response is cacheable, CloudFront caches the *modified* response.  That is the exact reason why Origin Response triggers do not fire on cache hits -- it would be redundant.  The result of the trigger, including any modifications to the response, is what will be served from the cache on subsequent requests, assuming the response is  considered cacheable after the trigger finishes.

Comment: Got it! The problem is that I am hosting a single page application and index.html is not cacheable, so every single request to index.html will be a cache miss. But the problem is: even for other requests which are not cacheable I would like to change the response status code and not cache it.

It's a shame that edge lambda does not allow to change http status code on viewer response. To solve that, I am using cache headers burst, which is not good because its forcing cloud front keep multiple versions of a file just to execute origin response event always.